# Using a map of HLists doesn't compile

Tags: scala, shapeless

This probably will be a series of question but I have to start from somewhere. I'm trying to create a map `String => HList` and in runtime access to them by key but compiler is not happy with it. Look at the following example (you can copy and paste it and run it):

The reason for the map is that the access to these `Exe` is in runtime. I am adding a function, e.g. `runExe` here to show the runtime usecase a bit better:

```scala
import shapeless._

import scala.util.Random
trait ExeLike[Args <: HList, +O] {
  def id: String
  def map(ar:Args):O
  def numArgs:Int

}

case class WithRunTime[Args <:HList, O](args:Args, exeLike: ExeLike[Args, O]) {
  def run: O = exeLike.map(args)
}

case class Exe0[O](id:String, map0: () => O) extends ExeLike[HNil, O] {
  override def numArgs: Int = 0
  override def map(args: HNil): O = map0()
}

case class Exe1[I, O](id:String, map1: I => O) extends ExeLike[I :: HNil, O] {
  override def numArgs: Int = 1
  override def map(args: I :: HNil): O = map1(args.head)
}

case class Exe2[I1, I2, O](id:String, map2: (I1, I2) => O) extends ExeLike[I1 :: I2 :: HNil, O] {
  override def numArgs: Int = 2
  override def map(args: I1 :: I2 :: HNil): O = map2(args.head, args(1))
}


object PlayGroundShapeless extends App {
//  def runExe[Args <: HList, +O](name:String, allFuncs:Map[String, ExeLike[Args, O]) = WithRunTime(10 :: 12 :: HNil, allFuncs(name))

  val ToString = Exe1("toString", (int: Int) => int.toString)
  val Sum = Exe2("Sum", (a0: Int, a1: Int) => a0 + a1)
  val RandomInt = Exe0("randomNumber", () => Random.nextInt())
  val allFuncs = List(ToString, Sum, RandomInt).map(a => a.id -> a).toMap


  val runnableSum = WithRunTime(10 :: 12 :: HNil, allFuncs("Sum")) //dose not compile
  //val runnableSum = WithRunTime(10 :: 12 :: HNil, Sum) //compile

  println(runnableSum.run)

}
```

The compiler errors:

```
Error:(448, 21) no type parameters for method apply: (args: Args, exeLike: ExeLike[Args,O])WithRunTime[Args,O] in object WithRunTime exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Int :: Int :: shapeless.HNil, Product with Serializable with ExeLike[_ >: shapeless.HNil with Int :: Int :: shapeless.HNil with Int :: shapeless.HNil <: shapeless.HList, Any])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Product with Serializable with ExeLike[_ >: shapeless.HNil with Int :: Int :: shapeless.HNil with Int :: shapeless.HNil <: shapeless.HList, Any]
 required: ExeLike[?Args,?O]
  val runnableSum = WithRunTime(10 :: 12 :: HNil, allFuncs("Sum"))
Error:(448, 36) type mismatch;
 found   : Int :: Int :: shapeless.HNil
 required: Args
  val runnableSum = WithRunTime(10 :: 12 :: HNil, allFuncs("Sum"))
Error:(448, 59) type mismatch;
 found   : Product with Serializable with ExeLike[_ >: shapeless.HNil with Int :: Int :: shapeless.HNil with Int :: shapeless.HNil <: shapeless.HList, Any]
 required: ExeLike[Args,O]
  val runnableSum = WithRunTime(10 :: 12 :: HNil, allFuncs("Sum"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `allFuncs` has existential type

```
Map[String, ExeLike[_ >: (HNil with (Int :: Int :: HNil) with (Int :: HNil)) <: HList, Any]]`
```

so `allFuncs("Sum")` has type

```
ExeLike[_ >: (HNil with (Int :: HNil) with (Int :: Int :: HNil)) <: HList, Any]
```

so we should downcast

```
val runnableSum = WithRunTime((10 :: 12 :: HNil).asInstanceOf[HNil with (Int :: HNil) with (Int :: Int :: HNil)], allFuncs("Sum"))

println(runnableSum.run) // 22
```

If you want to make it more type-safe, since `allFuncs` is supposed to return different types `Exe0[Int]`, `Exe1[Int, String]`, `Exe2[Int, Int, Int]` depending on value of argument, you should make `allFuncs` a `Poly`

```
object allFuncs extends Poly1 {
  implicit val toStr: Case.Aux["toString", Exe1[Int, String]] = at(_ => ToString)
  implicit val sum: Case.Aux["Sum", Exe2[Int, Int, Int]] = at(_ => Sum)
  implicit val rnd: Case.Aux["randomNumber", Exe0[Int]] = at(_ => RandomInt)
}

val runnableSum = WithRunTime(10 :: 12 :: HNil, allFuncs["Sum"]("Sum"))

println(runnableSum.run) // 22
```

---

In 2.12

```
object allFuncs extends Poly1 {
  implicit val toStr: Case.Aux[Witness.`"toString"`.T, Exe1[Int, String]] = at(_ => ToString)
  implicit val sum: Case.Aux[Witness.`"Sum"`.T, Exe2[Int, Int, Int]] = at(_ => Sum)
  implicit val rnd: Case.Aux[Witness.`"randomNumber"`.T, Exe0[Int]] = at(_ => RandomInt)
}

import shapeless.syntax.singleton._
val runnableSum = WithRunTime(10 :: 12 :: HNil, allFuncs[Witness.`"Sum"`.T]("Sum".narrow)) 
println(runnableSum.run) // 22
```

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned the reason I want to have access to these in runtime so I think literal types won't help. Also on 2.12

Comment: @Omid In the first approach downcasting is at runtime. In 2.12 you can have singleton types with `shapeless.Witness` (see update).

Comment: Yes, but you have to know the type if you want to downcast it. is it possible to add a rule to asset that the type of args is going to be compatible with the Exe ?

Comment: @Omid You can downcast to `HNil with (Nothing :: HNil) with (Nothing :: Nothing :: HNil) with ... with (Nothing :: Nothing :: ... :: Nothing :: HNil)` where the length is not less then actual length of the hlist (in the example with `toString`, `Sum`, `randomNumber` the length of the type to downcast the hlist to should be not less than 3).

Comment: @Omid Try `def runExe[Args <: HList, O](name: String, allFuncs: Map[String, ExeLike[Args, O]]) =
    WithRunTime(10 :: 12 :: HNil, allFuncs(name).asInstanceOf[ExeLike[HList, O]])`.

Comment: That won't compile :/

Comment: So we loose all the type info by casting to Any and HList. I hope there was a better way.

Comment: @Omid Well, in order to have some information at compile time you should know something at compile time. If we know something only at runtime what can we expect?